# Is it possible for a website to refuse access from a Python Selenium script?

Tags: python, selenium

I try to make a script logging on to a website, and I think my code is correct, but gets the following error code: "Could not connect because the destination computer actively denied it"
Is it possible to make a website that can refuse access for Selenium?
I have inserted the entire error code here, sorry that the last part is in Danish:
[Shell Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaz5k.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

It's possible that the website has no services listening on the specified port, or there is a firewall stopping you.

Comment: Thanks, Its actually not a website but a Fast Ethernet Micro Switch  with PoE from Microsence that have a webinterface, I dont know if it is doing any difference.